# Laravel array value get to show one by one

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

**My database**

[image: Database]

**My blade view**

[image: Blade view]

**But I want to have this**

[image: Desired solution]

**My controller**

```php
$profiles= Profile::where('id', $id)->get();
        
return view('artists.profile_edit',compact('profiles'));
```

**My blade template**

```php
@foreach ($profiles as $key => $profile)
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3 {{ $errors->has('social_media_channel_name') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="social_media_channel_name[]" value="{{  $profile['social_media_channel_name'] }}" placeholder="Social Media Channel Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3 {{ $errors->has('social_media_channel_link') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="social_media_channel_link[]" value="{{  $profile['social_media_channel_link'] }}" placeholder="Social Media Channel Link">
     </div>
@endforeach
```

Here I am trying to get array data and show in blade one by one.

Comment: Your images are missing, and what is your question?

Comment: update image.how to show array values in blade

Comment: You can cast the class attribute as  array in your model:   https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: I think profile should be single data or the ```id``` youre passing here: ```$profiles= Profile::where('id', $id)->get();``` can return more than one result? If it is one, you dont need `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think your database needs to be redesigned, because currently it's possible to have the array of names and the array of links a different size, which doesn't make sense.

But using this design, you'll need your "for" loop to loop by number instead by "foreach".  Get the minimum array length of names and links, and then loop through those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

### Update 1.0

I thinks that these columns from `json` or `longtext` MySQL type So, you need to use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) method to convert this string into array like so

```
@foreach (json_decode($profiles['social_media_channel_name']) as $profile)
    {{-- `$loop` is a variable that comes with `@for`, `@foreach`, and `@forelse` --}}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3 {{ $errors->has('social_media_channel_name') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="social_media_channel_name[]" value="{{  json_decode($profiles['social_media_channel_name'])[$loop->index] }}" placeholder="Social Media Channel Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3 {{ $errors->has('social_media_channel_link') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="social_media_channel_link[]" value="{{  json_decode($profiles['social_media_channel_link'])[$loop->index] }}" placeholder="Social Media Channel Link">
     </div>
@endforeach
```

Well, according to your last comment, this means that `$profiles['social_media_channel_name']` from type `array` So, your code must be like so

```
@foreach ($profiles['social_media_channel_name'] as $profile)
    {{-- `$loop` is a variable that comes with `@for`, `@foreach`, and `@forelse` --}}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3 {{ $errors->has('social_media_channel_name') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="social_media_channel_name[]" value="{{  json_decode($profiles['social_media_channel_name'])[$loop->index] }}" placeholder="Social Media Channel Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3 {{ $errors->has('social_media_channel_link') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="social_media_channel_link[]" value="{{  json_decode($profiles['social_media_channel_link'])[$loop->index] }}" placeholder="Social Media Channel Link">
     </div>
@endforeach
```

You can read more alse about [The Loop Variable](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#the-loop-variable)

Comment: Undefined array key "social_media_channel_name"

Comment: I found out about your issue. You want to get the profile with a specific passed `id` So, you must use the `first` method instead of `get` like so, `$profiles = Profile::where('id', $id)->first();` to get ONLY one instance instead of `Collection`.

Comment: json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given